# Multi-index variable depending on signature of permutation of indices

Tags: function-construction, symbolic, permutation, index

I do have some multi-indexed variable, e.g. like this

\begin{align*}f_{123} &= 1\\f_{345} &= 1/2\end{align*}

where $f$ is antisymmetric under permutation of any pair of indices, i.e. e.g. $f_{132}=-1$ and so on. Also, $f_{ijk}=0$ for $(ijk)$ not being a permutation of either $(123)$ or $(345)$. I am wondering what the right "Mathematica way" is to set up such a scenario.

**My current attempt**:

Define all values depending on the indices

```
ClearAll[f, f2];
f[{1, 2, 3}] = 1;
f[{3, 4, 5}] = 1/2;
```

Explicitly set all `f` to zero if their argument is not `{1,2,3}` or `{3,4,5}`.

```
f[list_ /; list != {1, 2, 3} || {3, 4, 5}] := 0;
```

Then define an `f2` which takes a 3dim `list` as argument, evaluates the `Signature[list]` and multiplies with `f` called with `Sort`ed `list`:

```
 f2[list_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &) /; Length[list] == 3] := Signature[list]*f[Sort@list];
```

This works as I want it to work. However, I feel like there must be another way to accomplish this - and I actually think that my attempt is not the best one (I have a gut feeling that it might miss certain cases and lead to errors at some point).

P.S.: If you do have better suggestions for Tags, I would much appreciate an edit/suggestion.

Comment: I'd have done `f[idx_ /; ! MatchQ[Sort[idx], {1, 2, 3} | {4, 5, 6}]] := 0` myself.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thanks for the suggestion. Of course, it is way more practicable to just use `f[_]=0`, not thinking straight there :)

Comment: That depends on your application. Would you want, say, `f["stuff"]` or `f[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]` to return 0 as well?

Comment: @J.M. That's right. Actually, in the way I need it right now it doesn't matter whether I use `f[_]:=0` or the explicitly stated "zero cases". However, it is true that this might cause issues if the code develops. So I will probably stick to explicitly stating when `f` should be zero and when it should stay unevaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since v10.1 you can use also [`OrderlessPatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html) like this :

```
f[x : {OrderlessPatternSequence[1, 2, 3]}] := Signature[x]*1
f[x : {OrderlessPatternSequence[3, 4, 5]}] := Signature[x]*1/2
```

then

```
f[{2, 1, 3}]
```

> `-1`

or

```
f[{5, 3, 4}]
```

> `1/2`

Comment: That is really nice! Unfortunately I am still using 10.0.1 and cannot make use of `OrderlessPatternSequence`. But that seems to a very elegant solution which is also exremely transparent

Comment: I learned something!

Comment: I decided to accept this answer (although I cannot use it) since it appears to me as the most elegant approach that also differs most from how I did it.

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant, but (hopefully) transparent:

The basic data

```
p1 = {1, 2, 3}; pp1 = Permutations[p1];
p2 = {4, 5, 6}; pp2 = Permutations[p2];
```

The function

```
g[x_] := Which[MemberQ[pp1, x], Signature[x], MemberQ[pp2, x], 
         Signature[x]/2, True, 0]

(* or ending with 1/2] in which case x is returned unevaluated *)
```

All tuples

```
t = Tuples[Range[6], 3];
Length[%] == 6^3

(* Out[84]= True *)
```

Check g on t

```
{#, g[#]} & /@ t;
Select[%, #[[2]] != 0 &]

(*
{{{1, 2, 3}, 1}, {{1, 3, 2}, -1}, {{2, 1, 3}, -1}, {{2, 3, 1}, 
  1}, {{3, 1, 2}, 1}, {{3, 2, 1}, -1}, {{4, 5, 6}, 1/
  2}, {{4, 6, 5}, -(1/2)}, {{5, 4, 6}, -(1/2)}, {{5, 6, 4}, 1/
  2}, {{6, 4, 5}, 1/2}, {{6, 5, 4}, -(1/2)}}
*)
```

Comment: I don't see the sign change anywhere...

Comment: @J.M. oops, you are right, I missed it. Now corrected. BTW your elegant solution can't possibly be beaten.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Indeed a very transparent solution and I like (from a pedagogic point of view) the combination of `Permutations` and `MemberQ`. Thanks for this

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
f[{1, 2, 3}] = 1;
f[{3, 4, 5}] = 1/2;
f[list_List /; Not[OrderedQ[list]]] := Signature[list] f[Sort@list]
```

Only bind the last definition if the argument isn't sorted, in which case sort and use `Signature` to get the correct sign.  Then `f[{3,2,1}]` yields `-1` and `f[{4,5,3}]` yields `1/2`.  You can then add `f[___]:=0` default, if you want.  With that default, `f[{1,2,3,4}]` and `f[{5,1,2,3,4}]` yield 0.

You can instead add the default

```
f[list_ /; OrderedQ[list] && Not[MemberQ[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}, list]]] := 0
```

but this line *MUST* come after the previous list-reordering definition.

Comment: Also pretty compact solution. Thank you!

Comment: There might be a smart way to use the `DownValues` of `f` to smartly rewrite the last clause in the last line there.

Answer (score 2):

depending on how you use it , it might be good performance-wise to precompute an array:

```
fa = SparseArray[
   Flatten[
    Function[{t},
      (  # -> t[[2]] & /@ NestList[RotateLeft, t[[1]], 2])] /@
      { {{1, 2, 3},   1},
        {{2, 1, 3},  -1},
        {{3, 4, 5}, 1/2},
        {{4, 3, 5},-1/2} }, 1] (*,{n,n,n}*) ];
                                  (* ^ add dimension spec to handle #>5 *)
f[list_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &) /; Length[list] == 3 &&
     Max[list] <= 5] := Extract[fa, list]   

f /@ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 5}, {3, 2, 1},{1,4,5}}
```

> {1, -(1/2), -1, 0}

Comment: That looks pretty compact. However, I do not understand what the `NestList[...]` part does (and consequently what it is needed for). Could you elaborate on that briefly?

Comment: evaluate this: `NestList[RotateLeft,{1, 2, 3}, 2]`, it should be clear.

Comment: True. In what case do you think is the precomputed array favorable? Even for 20 nonzero values, the result is given instantly. So I suspect maybe for more than 3 indices and a few 100 nonzero values?